# VHDL ERROR:Pack:2811 - Directed packing was unable to obey the user design

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, bit-shift, mux

I am working on a project in VHDL where I need to take a 4 bit input from switches, and shift it right or left a certain number of bits depending on values of other switches a button that switches between right/ and left shift. However, when I try to implement my code in Xilinx ISE I get the following error: ERROR:Pack:2811 - Directed packing was unable to obey the user design constraints (LOC=T10) which requires the combination of the symbols listed below to be packed into a single IOB component. My questions is what is causing this error and how can I fix it.

My code:

BarrelShifter.vhd

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

    -- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
    -- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
    --use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

    -- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
    -- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
    --library UNISIM;
    --use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

    entity BarrelShifter is
    Port ( switchInput : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
            switchMode : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           switchSelect : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
              switchCopy : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           buttonInput : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A,B,C,D,E,F,G,DP : out  STD_LOGIC;
           ax : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           display : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
    end BarrelShifter;

    architecture Behavioral of BarrelShifter is

    signal b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7: std_logic;

    Component InputMux is
    Port(bitInput : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           shiftMode : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
              shiftSelect : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           buttonInput : in  STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    begin

    switchMux : InputMux 
    port map(
    bitInput => switchInput,
    shiftMode => switchMode,
    shiftSelect => switchSelect,
    buttonInput => buttonInput
    );

    with switchInput select
    display <= "11111100" when "0000", --0
             "01100000" when "0001", --1
              "11011010" when "0010", --2
              "11110010" when "0011", --3
              "01100110" when "0100", --4
              "10110110" when "0101", --5
              "10111110" when "0110", --6
              "11100000" when "0111", --7
              "11111110" when "1000", --8
              "11100110" when "1001", --9
              "11101110" when "1010", --A
              "00111110" when "1011", --b
              "10011100" when "1100", --C
              "01111010" when "1101", --d
              "10011110" when "1110", --E
                  "10001110" when "1111"; --F

    b0 <= display(7);
    b1 <= display(6);
    b2 <= display(5);
    b3 <= display(4); 
    b4 <= display(3);
    b5 <= display(2);
    b6 <= display(1);
    b7 <= display(0);

    a <= NOT b0;
    b <= NOT b1;
    c <= NOT b2;
    d <= NOT b3;
    e <= NOT b4;
    f <= NOT b5;
    g <= NOT b6;
    dp <= NOT b7;

    ax <= "0111";
    end Behavioral;
```

InputMux.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity InputMux is
    Port ( bitInput : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           shiftMode : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
              shiftSelect : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           buttonInput : in  STD_LOGIC);
end InputMux;

architecture Behavioral of InputMux is

begin

shiftMode(0) <= shiftSelect(0);
shiftMode(1) <= shiftSelect(1);
shiftMode(2) <= buttonInput;

with shiftMode select
bitInput <= bitInput and "0" when "001";
end Behavioral;
```

The UCF file is a Nexys 3 (the board I am working on) master UCF which I have modified.

```
## This file is a general .ucf for Nexys3 rev B board
## To use it in a project:
## - remove or comment the lines corresponding to unused pins
## - rename the used signals according to the project

## 7 segment display
NET ax<0> LOC = N16;
NET ax<1> LOC = N15;
NET ax<2> LOC = P18;
NET ax<3> LOC = P17;

NET A         LOC = T17  ;#Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L51P_M1DQ12,                    Sch name = CA
NET B         LOC = T18  ;#Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L51N_M1DQ13,                    Sch name = CB
NET C         LOC = U17  ;#Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L52P_M1DQ14,                    Sch name = CC
NET D         LOC = U18  ;#Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L52N_M1DQ15,                    Sch name = CD
NET E         LOC = M14  ;#Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L53P,                           Sch name = CE
NET F         LOC = N14  ; #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L53N_VREF,                      Sch name = CF
NET G         LOC = L14  ;  #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L61P,                           Sch name = CG
NET DP        LOC = M13  ; #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L61N,                           Sch name = DP

NET buttonInput LOC = T10 ;
#NET "an<0>"          LOC = "N16" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L50N_M1UDQSN,                   Sch name = AN0
#NET "an<1>"          LOC = "N15" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L50P_M1UDQS,                    Sch name = AN1
#NET "an<2>"          LOC = "P18" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L49N_M1DQ11,                    Sch name = AN2
#NET "an<3>"          LOC = "P17" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L49P_M1DQ10,                    Sch name = AN3


## Leds
#NET "Led<0>"         LOC = "U16" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L2P_CMPCLK,                     Sch name = LD0
#NET "Led<1>"         LOC = "V16" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L2N_CMPMOSI,                    Sch name = LD1
#NET "Led<2>"         LOC = "U15" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L5P,                            Sch name = LD2
#NET "Led<3>"         LOC = "V15" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L5N,                            Sch name = LD3
#NET "Led<4>"         LOC = "M11" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L15P,                           Sch name = LD4
#NET "Led<5>"         LOC = "N11" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L15N,                           Sch name = LD5
#NET "Led<6>"         LOC = "R11" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L16P,                           Sch name = LD6
#NET "Led<7>"         LOC = "T11" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L16N_VREF,                      Sch name = LD7


## Switches
#NET "sw<0>"          LOC = "T10" | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L29N_GCLK2,                     Sch name = SW0
#NET "sw<1>"          LOC = "T9"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L32P_GCLK29,                    Sch name = SW1
#NET "sw<2>"          LOC = "V9"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L32N_GCLK28,                    Sch name = SW2
#NET "sw<3>"          LOC = "M8"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L40P,                           Sch name = SW3
#NET "sw<4>"          LOC = "N8"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L40N,                           Sch name = SW4
#NET "sw<5>"          LOC = "U8"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L41P,                           Sch name = SW5
#NET "sw<6>"          LOC = "V8"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 2, Pin name = IO_L41N_VREF,                      Sch name = SW6
#NET "sw<7>"          LOC = "T5"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = MISC, Pin name = IO_L48N_RDWR_B_VREF_2,          Sch name = SW7
NET switchInput<3> LOC = T5;
NET switchInput<2> LOC = V8;
NET switchInput<1> LOC = U8;
NET switchInput<0> LOC = N8;
NET switchSelect<0> LOC = T10;
NET switchSelect<1> LOC = T9;

## Buttons
#NET "btn<0>"         LOC = "B8"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 0, Pin name = IO_L33P,                           Sch name = BTNS
#NET "btn<1>"         LOC = "A8"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 0, Pin name = IO_L33N,                           Sch name = BTNU
#NET "btn<2>"         LOC = "C4"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 0, Pin name = IO_L1N_VREF,                       Sch name = BTNL
#NET "btn<3>"         LOC = "C9"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 0, Pin name = IO_L34N_GCLK18,                    Sch name = BTND
#NET "btn<4>"         LOC = "D9"  | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33";   #Bank = 0, Pin name = IO_L34P_GCLK19,                    Sch name = BTNR
```

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned input pin T10 to two different nets.

```
NET buttonInput LOC = T10 ;
NET switchSelect<0> LOC = T10;
```

The error suggests the tools don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why this error occurs is that you may have assigned same Loc (locations)  to two or more variables!
I had the same error because of that.
Hope this resolves your issue.